# How to export the layers of an eps file into seperate files

Tags: image, imagemagick-convert

I have an eps file with multiple layers and I would like to have a command line tool that splits the eps file into seperate files (one file for each layer).

The resulting files can be of either format (vector or raster).

Comment: Could you share a file to test with?

Comment: https://thieme-dam-resized.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/multilayer.eps . This file has a layer with checmical elements, and a layer with red circles. The requirement is having both layers as seperate files

Comment: Mmmm, could you check that file please? Neither ImageMagick nor PIL/Pillow nor Photoshop seems to be able to find multiple layers in it...

Comment: You re right, I don t get to see them in Photoshop or imagemagick either.  But I do see the 2 layers in Adobe Illustrator.