# How to remove spot color (s) from an image

Tags: imagemagick, ghostscript, imagemagick-convert

Is there a command line tool to remove all spot color channels from a vector input image (type can be ai, eps) and keep only the CMYK or RGB color channels .

What I ve been able to come up with so far is using ghostscript tiffsep device and then recombine the color channel images to one image using imagemagicks -combine option. The drawback of this method is that it is quite compicated and I end up with a tiff image, instead of the original (vector) format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Image' has a defined meaning in PostScript, it means a bitmap, a raster. I think, from the context, that you mean something more general.

The simple answer is no, in general you can't do this, and I don't know of any tool which will.

The reason is that to do so would lose information; the marks defined in Separation or DeviceN space would be lost entirely, and its generally regarded as a Bad Idea to discard random parts of the document.

Perhaps you could explain what you are trying to achieve with this (ie why are you doing this), and it might be possible to suggest an alternative method.

If you are a competent C programmer you could produce a Ghostscript subclass device using the existing FILTER device (in gdevflt.c) as a template. That device looks at the type of operation, and either passes it on to the output device, or throws it away. It would be reasonably simple to look at the current colour space and discard Separation or DeviceN space. If you then uses the pdfwrite/ps2write/eps2write outptu device you'd get an EPS, PostScript program or PDF file as the output.

Whether you go down this route, continue with what you have, or find an alternative approach, there are a couple of things you need to think about; how do you plan to tackle Separation inks with process colour names ? Eg /Separation /Black. What about DeviceN spaces where some of the inks are process colours ? Eg a duotone Black and Pantone ink. Should these be preserved or dicarded ?

Your current approach will use the parts of the object which mark process plates, but not those which mark spot colorus, which could give some very peculiar results.

[EDIT]

PDF, PostScript and EPS don't have 'layers' (PDF has a feature, Optional Content, which uses the term 'layers' as a description in the specification but that's all).

An application such as Photoshop and Illustrator can have layers, but in general what they export to has to have those 'layers' converted into something else. That 'something else' depends on what you are saving it as.

Part of the problem is that you are apparently trying to deal with 3 different kinds of input, you say Illustrator (PDF, more or less), Photoshop (raster image) and EPS (PostScript). There is little common ground between the 3, is there a reason to support all of them ?

If you are content to stick with just Illustrator you might be able to do something with Optional Content. I'm not terribly familiar with modern versions of Illustrator, but wouldn't it be simpler to save two versions of the file, one with the answer layer and one without ?

Anyway, Ghostscript can honour Optional Content, so if you can save a PDF file (**not** PostScript or EPS) from Illustrator, it may be that the layers will persist into the PDF as Optional Content. I suspect they will going by a quick Google. In that case you might be able to run the file through Ghostscript, telling it not to honour the Optional Content portion, and get a PDF file without it present.

Another solution (again limited to PDF) would be to open the PDF file with an editing application such as Acrobat Pro, and simply delete the bits you don't want. Deletion of that kind is relatively reliable.

It still feels like rather a long-winded way to get a PDF file with some of the content removed though. I can't help feeling that just saving two versions from the creating application would be easier.

Comment: My use case is that I have an asset(image) which shows a question for a student. The solution of this question is also present inside the same asset. The solution is drawn only in a single spot color. So my goal is to extract the "question only" image (remove the "solution" part of the image). A different approach can be to use multiple layers for question and solution instead of a spot color, but I can t find a way to export seperate layers in a vector file either (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57753942 )

Comment: Hi Ken, thank you so much for your explanation. I have managed to use ghostscript to convert my eps or ai file to a pdf file with my "layers" showing up as OCG's. Now I m trying to find out how to do : "telling it not to honour the Optional Content portion". Is there perhaps an option in ghostscript for the pdfwrite device?

Comment: I don't have an example to hand to test with, so this is from memory; basically you need to turn off the optional content you don't want to see, and then run it through Ghostscript. Its the PDF interpreter which determines whether or not a OCG gets processed or not, if its set to Off, it won't get processed and so won't be sent to pdfwrite. If its not /Off then its more complex, there's some info here http://git.ghostscript.com/?p=ghostpdl.git;a=commitdiff;h=9e621d6ffb0e29c5de8331bf2c95003c8cf85941

Comment: If you can make an example available I can play with it, but without that I'm sort of whistling in the dark.

Comment: Indeed, I used the IText library to set my ocg layer to off in my pdf, and then ghostscript removes the layer when I run the pdf through pngalpha or jpeg DEVICE.  thx for the support!

Comment: No problem, glad to hear it is working for you now.